# Maven error : diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.6

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

Many topics have been opened about the subject but i can not solve the problem with the same method. i get followed error when compiling with Maven.  When i rebuilt it in Debug mode, i saw that it were compiled with 1.6 again although Java Version was defined as 1.7 in JAVA_HOME and installed JRE in Eclipse. i have tried adding the following to both the root directory and the sub-project directory, but the problem is still going on.

*Error message*

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project attendance-api: Compilation failure
[ERROR] /D:/repository/sakai107/attendance/api/src/java/org/sakaiproject/attendance/model/AttendanceSite.java:[49,127] diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.6
[ERROR] (use -source 7 or higher to enable diamond operator)
```

*AttendanceSite.java:[49,127]*

```
@Getter @Setter private Set<AttendanceStatus>   attendanceStatuses  = new HashSet<>(0);
```

*Maven debug output*

```
<source default-value="1.5">1.6</source>
```

*pom.xml (root)*

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

*pom.xml (in project folder)*

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

Comment: `<artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>` => use compiler instead of javadoc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `JAVA_HOME` variable is usually only used by the `mvn` command to figure out with where the JDK is, but that should not affect compiler settings (unless, of course, that you need a JDK with version equal or above your compiler settings).

You can configure the `maven-compiler-plugin` not only via properties (e.g., `maven.compiler.source`) but also directly in the plugin definition (which I would consider the safer option). Just add this to your plugin definition.

```
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.1</version>
    <configuration>
      <source>1.7</source>
      <target>1.7</target>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Answer (score 1):

This can also being achieved by using:

```xml
<properties>
  <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
  <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
</properties>
```

Comment: Thanks, actually first, i did it as you specify, but it did not work then i added in main pom.xml but this time i specified the parameter incorrectly.